# Umbraco 6 with MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, umbraco

We want to create an MVC4 web application implementing some business workflows that has to be implemented using MVC4 Framework. This web aplication shall also have a huge documentation part that shall be handled best using a CMS, like Umbraco.

So, we have chosen Umbraco as the infrastructure, implemented CMS pages, and now we want to add application logic inside.

If we extend RenderMvcController, we face with some limitations as we have to stick with the Umbraco libraries.

Is it possible to use raw MVC4 engine, the basic Controller class, and also the standard view pages that do not inherit from anything else side-by-side with Umbraco 6 CMS engine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can pretty much do what you like with it, as long as you're on version 6.1+ I think.

This umbraco page might help, it has details of [overriding the custom controller](https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/reference/routing/custom-controllers) in global.asax.

```
public class MyApplication : UmbracoApplication 
{
    protected override void OnApplicationStarting(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DefaultRenderMvcControllerResolver.Current.SetDefaultControllerType(typeof(MyCustomUmbracoController));
        base.OnApplicationStarting(sender, e);
    } 
}
```

Comment: Tested, but nope! The new custom controller shall be inherited from RenderMvcController, hence the error: "The Type specified (MyCustomUmbracoController) is not of type Umbraco.Web.Mvc.RenderMvcController"

Comment: Hmm. It should be possible to run plain MVC alongside Umbraco stuff by inheriting from Umbraco.Web.Mvc.RenderMvcController and overriding the Index method, as demonstrated [here](http://www.ben-morris.com/using-umbraco-6-to-create-an-asp-net-mvc-4-web-applicatio).

Comment: Yes, indeed! You have to extend RenderMvcController, however you have full power of MVC. Thanks v6.1!

Comment: Link is broken. It would nice to get an updated link